# Specify relative path server in file_put_content() in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, relative-path

I've been looking for a method for putting a relative path into the `file_put_content()` function of PHP. Basically I want to copy one file to one of the directory of my server. Here is what I've done so far:

```
function curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        $image_new = curl($image);
        file_put_contents("/minimaled_server_path/app/webroot/logo_url",
                          $image_new);
```

It's throwing me the error below:

```
file_put_contents(/minimal_server_path/app/webroot/logo_url)
  [function.file-put-contents]:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
  [APP/Controller/AppsController.php, line 105]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try removing the leading slash from the file path. Relative paths do not begin with a slash, absolute paths do. Also, consider using `fopen()` and passing the handle to `CURLOPT_FILE`, it will be much more efficient.

Comment: I've changed my code as you've told. but still it doesn't get resolved

Comment: Still the same error? Try `echo getcwd();` to make sure you are working in the directory you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use realpath function to calculate the path from the file you execute the function

```
file_put_contents(realpath("/../../minimaled_server_path/app/webroot/logo_url"), $image_new);
```